# How do I print a strucure in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

We can print elements of a structure using `structure.element`. But I want to print a complete structure at once.

Is there a method something like `cout<<strucutre`, the same way we can print a list or tuple in Python.

This is what I want:

```
struct node {
  int next;
  string data;
};

main()
{
  node n;
  cout<<n;
}
```

Comment: overload the operator <<

Comment: Everything you want to know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: You have to overload the `std::ostream& Operator<<(std::ostream&, const node&)` operator to do so.

Comment: An alternative to overloading `<<` is to create a `toString()` class method so you can do `cout << n.toString();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overload the << operator properly:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
struct node {
    int next;
    std::string data;
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const node& myNode) {
        stream << "next: " << myNode.next << ", Data: " << myNode.data << std::endl;
        return stream;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    node n{1, "Hi"};

    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should override the << operator for the object `cout`. But `cout` is an object of class ostream so you cannot just simply overload the << operator for that class. You have to use a friend function. The function body would look like this:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream & in, const node& n){
    in << "(" << n.next << "," << n.data << ")" << endl;
    return in;
}
```

The function is friend, in case if you have private data in your class.